# Does Eclipse Java EE IDE come with Tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am wondering if I need to download and install Tomcat separately or if it comes with the latest version of Eclipse EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download Apache Tomcat separately, but you are not required to install it. In fact, it's simpler if you don't. The best layout supported for getting the required Java EE runtime libraries from Tomcat as well as launching it from Eclipse is the one from the unpacked tar/zip files.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat and Eclipse has different types of license, and AFAIK Eclipse is "more free".